# How can I use Laravel's baseurl on the vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, pagination, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

I have 2 component

Component 1, The name is SearchResultVue.vue component

The component is like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <span class="pull-right" v-show="totalall>8">
            <pagination :data="list" :baseUrl="this.Laravel.baseUrl" :total="totalPage" :nextPage="nextPage" :prevPage="prevPage"></pagination>
        </span>
    ...
</template>
```

The component call component 2. The name is Pagination.vue component

The Pagination component is like this :

```
<template>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li>
                <a :href="prevPage" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li v-for="i in total">
                <a :href="baseUrl+'/search-result?page='+i">{{i}}</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a :href="nextPage" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props:['total', 'data', 'nextPage', 'prevPage'],
        computed:{
            baseUrl(){
                return window.Laravel.baseUrl
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When executed, in the console exist 2 error

Error 1 is like this :

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "Laravel" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive
>   data properties in the data option.

Error 2 is like this :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'baseUrl' of undefined

How can I solve the errors?

Comment: you can't access Laravel variables from VueJS. It is not anyhow defined in `window` ...

Comment: @M U, Then what is the right solution for my problem?

Comment: Why you need baseurl? It is env variable so you can set it in your webpack config and use it that way?

Comment: @M U, Because on the localhost and on the server, it's a different url. In the localhost, my url like this :`http://myshop.dev/search-result`. And on the server, my url like this : `http://myshop.ct-staging.tk/search-result`. How to set my webpack config?

Comment: posted full answer how you should do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to attach that to `window`. I think the confusion comes because Laravel makes the `csrf_token` available via `Laravel.csrfToken` but to do that it places the following in the `header`:

```
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
```

Personally, I don't like mixing `php` with `javascript`, but if you really want to add the `baseurl` to your global `Laravel` object, you could just do:

```
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
            'baseUrl' => base_url()
    ]); ?>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w6szt02q/

Comment: Seems you master vue.js. I need you help. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41952393/why-pagination-links-returns-json-when-clicked-vue-js-2. Maybe you can help me

Answer (score 3):

**Set env variables in your webpack config.**

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  BASE_URL: '"http://myshop.ct-staging.tk'",
}

// config/dev.env.js
module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  BASE_URL: '"http://myshop.dev/"' // this overrides the BASE_URL value of prod.env
})
```

**Use it in your Vue app.**

`Vue.config.baseurl = process.env.BASE_URL`

Comment: @M U, Where I can set my webpack config?

Comment: /project/config if you are using webpack vue template

Comment: @M U, my `/project/config` is like this: https://postimg.org/image/y5hfca1i9/. Seems I don't use webpack vue template

Comment: this is your laravel config.. where is your webpack config ?

Comment: @M U, How can I find it? Seems webpack config not exist

Comment: @mosestoh If you're using `elixir` you might want to take a look at the [elixir -webpack Github page](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-webpack-official)

Comment: @M U, I use it. But I don't find the config